# How to count instances of an specified char in a string in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've looked through everything relevant I can find on here, but for some reason nothing is helping. Whenever I run this I always end up with a result of 0. And no, I can not use other libraries for this (I saw some awesome solutions that have it down to one line, but I can't do that)

```
public void process()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your String:");
    String in_string = input.nextLine();

    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press 1 to count the occurrence of a particular letter.");
    System.out.println("Press 2 to count the total words in your input sentance.");
    System.out.println("Press 3 to change your input sentance.");
    System.out.println("Press 4 to exit.");

    int option = input2.nextInt();

    if (option==1)
    {
        System.out.println("Choose your letter: ");
        String in_occurence = input.nextLine();


        for(int i = 0 ; i < in_string.length(); i++)
        {
            if(in_occurence.equals(in_string.charAt(i)))
            {
                charCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(charCount);
    }
```

Comment: I think you may have missed some details. Where is `charCount` declared?

Comment: P.S. "occurrence" has two r's in it.  (I know this is a nitpick, but since I blew this exact word in a spelling bee 40 years ago, in the exact same way, I thought I ought to point it out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a `String` with a `char` using `String#equals()`. That will always give you `false`.

For example:

```
System.out.println("a".equals('a'));  // false
```

You should convert the `String` to `char` by getting character at index 0 before comparison:

```
if(in_occurence.charAt(0) == in_string.charAt(i))
```

or, just declare `in_occurrence` as `char` type:

```
char in_occurence = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a `String` to a `char` which is never equal even if the String contains that char.

What you want is

```
if (in_occurance.charAt(0) == in_string.charAt(i)) // compare char
```